# firebase-admin sdk not working after being compiled with webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, webpack, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use Webpack to compile a Node.js server that uses firebase-admin to connect and use Firestore. Here is the application code (boiled down)

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { firebase } from './support/environment'; // This is just constants

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(JSON.parse(firebase.serviceAccount))
});
const db = admin.firestore();

const a = async () => {

  var meeting = await db.collection("meetings")
    .where(
      "pin", "==", '1111')
    .where(
      "status", "==", "in-progress")
    .get();

  console.log('Completed query');
  console.log(meeting.empty, meeting.size);

};

a();
```

**When I run this code (after compiling the typescript) it executes normally**, the logs show `Completed query` as expected, no errors. After compiling using the command `webpack` (no cmd line args) and the following `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // Change to your "entry-point".
  entry: './src/app',
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.compiled.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    uws: 'uws',
    bufferutil: 'bufferutil',
    'utf-8-validate': 'utf-8-validate',
  }
};
```

I run the compiled file using `node dist/app.compiled.js` and I get the following error:

```
(node:14082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error reading first path in the walk /protos
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/protos'
    at EventEmitter.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js?:265:28)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at fn (webpack:///./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js?:100:17)
    at statter (webpack:///./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js?:137:7)
    at walkdir (webpack:///./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js?:269:3)
    at Function.walkdir.sync (webpack:///./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js?:15:10)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js?:50:6)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js?:288:30)
    at Object../node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js (/Users/marktdodds/Documents/Work/correly/server/dist/app.compiled.js:5736:1)
(node:14082) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14082) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried adding both `firebase` and `firebase-admin` under the `externals` object in the webpack config, doesn't make a difference. I have also tried compiling the code to `js` first using `tsc`, then bundling with webpack, and I get the same error.

So the webpack compiling is messing up the code somehow, but I'm at a loss. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would just skip webpack for backend code.  webpack majors in frontend web app assembly.  The TS compiler does just fine on its own.

Comment: The ts compiler does not have tree shaking and other optimization techniques. Also, attemping to deploy to the Cloud using only the tsc compiler results in unneeded dependencies getting packaged and deployed with your function. Webpack is fantastic for backend code as well due to size constraints on the zip size of cloud functions.

Comment: Facing the same issue. @mqrk Did you solve it?

Comment: @AmalShehu No sadly not, we ended up going in a different direction entirely.

Comment: Excluded that from webpack bundle, then used serverless webpack to deploy.